# Pyinstaller 3 adding datafiles with --onefile

Tags: python, python-3.x, executable, pyinstaller

I have a working Python 3 script, inventoryScraper.py, that I am trying to make into a 1 file executable I can distribute. I have been using Pyinstaller 3 with Python 3, it has worked in the past. I have a file 'Store_Codes.csv' that my script needs to run, and I want it included inside the executable.

I have read and attempted all the previous answers relating to this, and it has not worked/I messed it up. The resulting .exe works when the Store_Codes.csv is in the same folder as the exe, but not otherwise. I am definitely a novice to Python, but the person I'm giving this to has no experience whatsoever with command lines or anything related, so it's important it be an all-in-one file.

I have modified the spec file in every way I have seen on other posts, and none have worked, I am sure I am misunderstanding, and I could really use the help.

What is the straightforward way, with Pyinstaller 3, to include data files in a onefile exe?

Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

1. Put the `Store_Codes.csv` in the same folder as the .py file.
2. On the field `data` in the .spec file you add `datas=[( 'Store_Codes.csv', '.' )],`
3. You should add to your .py file

   ```
    if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
        # if you are running in a |PyInstaller| bundle
        extDataDir = sys._MEIPASS
        extDataDir  = os.path.join(extDataDir, 'Store_Codes.csv') 
        #you should use extDataDir as the path to your file Store_Codes.csv file
    else:
        # we are running in a normal Python environment
        extDataDir = os.getcwd()
        extDataDir = os.path.join(extDataDir, 'Store_Codes.csv') 
        #you should use extDataDir as the path to your file Store_Codes.csv file
   ```
4. compile the file.

## Discussion

When you start the `.exe` it creates a temporary folder in the appropriate temp-folder location for the OS. The folder is named `_MEIxxxxxx`, where xxxxxx is a random number. All the files you need to run the script will be there
  The `sys._MEIPASS` is the path for this temporary folder.

When you add `datas=[( 'Store_Codes.csv', '.' )]` to your spec file. It will copy the file to the main folder of the bundle. If you want to keep it organized you can create a different folder using `datas=[( 'Store_Codes.csv', 'another_folder' )]`, then in your code you would have

```
 if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
     # if you are running in a |PyInstaller| bundle
     extDataDir = sys._MEIPASS
     extDataDir  = os.path.join(extDataDir,another_folder, 'Store_Codes.csv') 
     #you should use extDataDir as the path to your file Store_Codes.csv file
 else:
     # we are running in a normal Python environment
     extDataDir = os.getcwd()
     extDataDir = os.path.join(extDataDir,another_folder 'Store_Codes.csv') 
     #you should use extDataDir as the path to your file Store_Codes.csv file
```

Answer (score 0):

Well there's actually an easiest work around, rename your `Store_Codes.csv` into `Store_Codes.py` then edit the file:

```
csv_codes = """

csv file content...

"""
```

In your main script: `import Store_Codes` and then `csv_file_content = Store_Codes.csv_codes`.

Then in `pyinstaller` use `--onefile`, it'll automatically include `Store_Codes.py` into your newly generated exe file.

**P.S.** If it's `utf-8` encoded content in the csv file, don't forget `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`

Comment: I did exactly as you wrote, but I get a "ImportError: no module named 'Store_Codes'"

Comment: Did you put `Store_Codes.py` into same folder with your main script?

Comment: I did, it still gives me an error, and I just tested the main script, it works as it should.

Comment: Then add this parameter in your `pyinstaller` command: `--hidden-import=Store_Codes`, this will make sure it includes the file while packaging